# Is there any method to create a draggable photo collage in canvas using jquery?

Tags: draggable, fabricjs, photo, photo-gallery

Currently i'm doing a project about create a draggable photo collage using canvas in html5, i'm using Fabricjs to create most of the function, is there any tutorial or method to create a photo collage using Fabricjs or using other library?

for the reference 
http://www.fotor.com/app.html#!module/collage/tool/ClassicTemplate